# Sublime2 keeps crashing? What is wrong with my python code?

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext2

I'm learning python, but this code keeps crashing my text editor.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
x = 12
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0

while abs (ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print 'low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', ans
    numGuesses += 1
    if ans**2 < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high - ans
    ans = (high + low)/2.0

print 'numGuesses =', numGuesses

print ans, 'is close to square root of', x
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: high = ans instead of high-ans

Comment: This code has certainly nothing to do with the editor crashing. And if it were, this would be off-topic and would belong to superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this instead:

```
x = 12
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0

while abs (ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print 'low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', ans
    numGuesses += 1
    if ans**2 < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high = ans
    ans = (high + low)/2.0

print 'numGuesses =', numGuesses

print ans, 'is close to square root of', x
```

Answer look like this:

```
low = 0.0 high = 12 ans = 6.0
low = 0.0 high = 6.0 ans = 3.0
low = 3.0 high = 6.0 ans = 4.5
low = 3.0 high = 4.5 ans = 3.75
low = 3.0 high = 3.75 ans = 3.375
low = 3.375 high = 3.75 ans = 3.5625
low = 3.375 high = 3.5625 ans = 3.46875
low = 3.375 high = 3.46875 ans = 3.421875
low = 3.421875 high = 3.46875 ans = 3.4453125
low = 3.4453125 high = 3.46875 ans = 3.45703125
numGuesses = 10
3.462890625 is close to square root of 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in an endless `while`-loop. When you have a look at this part:

```
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
```

`while abs(ans**2 - x)` always gives 24, while `epsilon` is set to 0.01.

When learning to program, while loops are tricky. They will keep your processor busy until you forcefully abort them. This is also what has been crashing your text editor.